# Android MPL package developer Download

Tags: android

I'm building an Android application and i want to integrate it with PayPal payment. 
I have to download the necessary libraries to use PayPal. 
PayPal documentation gives a link where choose the SDKs, but installing and using Java's once, the application crashes.
LogCat says that

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal`

Can anyone explain me which library i have to download and import?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the paypal jar is in the libs directory of your project. ProGuard will then process it and include it in the output jar.

With the `-libraryjars` option, ProGuard will read it, but not include it in the output jar, so you get a `NoClassDefFoundError`. See the [Proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/introduction.html)

Comment: I'm using 'PayPal_MPL.jar'and it is in the libs directory of my project. My doubt is that i'm using the wrong library ... do i need to download other libraries? And, most important, where i can download them?

Comment: well what libraries are you using

Comment: PayPal_MPL.jar , paypal-ndk.jar